# HTML5 App using Bluetooth

Tags: html, caching, bluetooth, offline

Recently, I was thinking of developing a HTML5 Game which can be played offline in different devices via storing information on Application Cache of a Browser and use bluetooth to make Multiplayer Game.Can anyone Suggest me if that is possible. And how to use Bluetooth to send Application data. Also if you have any idea of the time needed for development of such a thing by a beginner.